# Defining keys using push method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developing a simple shopping cart solution in JavaScript (Ionic 2 / Angular).

In PHP I just do the following:

```
<?php
$cart = array(
    48131 => array(
        'size' => 'STANDART',
        'qty' => 1,
    )
);

print_r($cart);
```

And the `48131` is the `index`, so after I can easily delete it (since I know that the `key` is `48131`).

This is my JavaScript code (an example):

```
function addToCart() {
    this.cart = [];

    this.cart.push({
        id: this.id,
        size: this.size,
        qty: this.qty
    });

    console.log(this.cart);
}
```

And this is what I get -

[image]

It looks like the push method just adds another key, starting from 0 (which I guess is normal). I've tried many things, I can't do it right... Can someone help?

Comment: `this.cart = {};this.cart[this.id] = [ "size": this.size,
        "qty": this.qty];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.cart = {};
function addToCart() {       
    this.cart[this.id]= {
        size: this.size,
        qty: this.qty
    };
   console.log(this.cart);
}
```

Comment: When I did it like that, on the second add, the console.log returns "(48132) [null, null, null, null...". Weird...

Comment: Yes, it will insert null into the remaining indices

Comment: So there's no other way? :-(

Comment: Or you can use objects instead of array as the updated code above. You can get the value like this.cart[id[

Comment: Never mind, it didn't worked the first time because I forgot to change `this.cart = []` to `this.cart = {}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
function addToCart() {
    this.cart = [];

    this.cart['48131'] = {
        id: this.id,
        size: this.size,
        qty: this.qty
    };

    console.log(this.cart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cart on angular side should have an object. And take an item into it something like this:
var cart = {};
cart[id] = {prop1: val1, prop2: val2};